# How to Dynamically Fetch excel Cell Range in Interop Excel using c#

Tags: c#, excel, range, interop, excel-interop

I am stuck in a situation where i have a dynamic pivot table that returns columns based on date range the user has selected

for eg : if user selects "Oct-2020" and "Feb-2021", following columns will be returned from datatable

| Name | Oct-2020 | Nov-2020 | Dec-2020 | Jan-2021 | Feb-2021 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

2. if user selects "Jan-2021" and "Feb-2021", following columns will be returned from datatable

| Name | Jan-2021 | Feb-2021 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

i have custom tables as shown above, so i have used interop excel to export the resultset into excel sheet, i need to color column names based on column count. i have hardcoded range values, since, i am not able to get range dynamically

how do i fetch excel range dynamically based on column count and color its background
please help me